# How to stop GCMBaseIntentService so that notification will not get received?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have implemented GCM successfully in almost all my app so that I can send notifications to my users. They are working good however now I want my user to decide whether they want notifications or not. Let's say there will be a toggle button which determines whether the device will be registered or unregistered.

I tried the below codes to unregister but with no success, I am still able to receive the notifications

```
GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
```

And

```
GCMRegistrar.unregister(this)
```

I can go with work arounds like I can put a flag of false on my server and so notification will not be sent at the point of origin or I wont listen to the notification in `onMessage()` if user disable option to receive notification however I don't want that.

I want that GCMRegistrar will be unregistered and the service (GCMBaseIntentService) will be stopped.

Comment: have you tried handler to unregister your gcm service ?

Comment: Could you please let me know the process?

Comment: @user3564321 One more thing I want to confirm does GCMBaseIntentService really runs in background cause I dont see my application in "Running" section of Application Manager however it still shows "Force Stop" when I click on that on "Downloaded" in Application Manager in Settings. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a static handler in your class where you are registering gcm

```
    static Handler mHandler;
```

and in your oncreate

```
mHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what == 0)
            {

                GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);

            }


        }
    };
```

now send message to handler to unregister this gcm like this.

```
        Message msg=MainActivity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg.what=0;
            MainActivity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

and this will fire handler of your mainActivity to unregister gcm.

try it ll help you.

Comment: thank you for the quick response....while I am trying your code could you please explain my last question which I asked about GCM?

Comment: However why does not it put the app name show in "Running" section of Application Manager of Settings?

Comment: dont know more abt this,you should use google or put this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: okay thanx....your handler code worked out. Thank, I will accept the answer. Thanx again.!!!